# Transform a vector of int to a vector of str

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to convert a `vector<int>` to a `vector<string>`. Using `std::transform` I used `std::to_string` to convert the `int` to `string` but I keep getting an error. Here's my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v_int;
    std::vector<std::string> v_str;

    for(int i = 0;i<5;++i)
        v_int.push_back(i);

    v_str.resize(v_int.size());
    std::transform(v_int.begin(),v_int.end(),v_str.begin(),std::to_string);
}
```

but I'm getting this error

```
 no matching function for call to 'transform'
        std::transform(v_int.begin(),v_int.end(),v_str.begin(),std::to_string);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1951:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument
      '_UnaryOperation'
transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterato...
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1961:1: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 4 were
      provided
transform(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1, _InputItera...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is an overloaded function, so you'll need to provide a cast to disambiguate

```
std::transform(v_int.begin(),v_int.end(),v_str.begin(),
               static_cast<std::string(*)(int)>(std::to_string));
```

Or use a lambda

```
std::transform(v_int.begin(),v_int.end(),v_str.begin(),
               [](int i){ return std::to_string(i); });
```

Comment: @gauravsehgal I'm casting it to a pointer to function type that takes an `int` argument and returns `std::string`. Since the OP has a `vector<int>`, that's the relevant overload from the list I linked to above.

Comment: @gauravsehgal The type in the cast is the same type as `to_string`'s overload for `int`. Its only effect is that it makes explicit which overload you want. You can view it as manual overload resolution.